# cannot import name 'register_extension_dtype' while importing pandas

Tags: pandas, import, jupyter-notebook, python-import

i am trying to import pandas but is giving me below error. Earlier it was giving me different errors but i fixed those. but now i am stuck on this one. Never had such a problem before while importing pandas.[image: This is the image about the problem]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are your to-do's -

1. Try shutting down and then restarting the notebook.
2. If 1 does not work, reinstall pandas using "conda install -f pandas" if using anaconda. Do not forget to shutdown and restart the notebook after the installation.